# unable to start RESTful web service

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have been learning RESTful web services and I am following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm) for that. Moreover, I have implemented the example code given in that tutorial but when I run it through [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), I am getting `404 Not Found` Error. My request URL in Postman is `http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users` with `GET`. Therefore please tell what can be the issue in my code?

**Request and Response:**

[image]

**Project Directory:**

[image]

**User.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.io.Serializable;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement; 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 
@XmlRootElement(name = "user") 

public class User implements Serializable {  
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
   private int id; 
   private String name; 
   private String profession;  
   public User(){} 

   public User(int id, String name, String profession){  
      this.id = id; 
      this.name = name; 
      this.profession = profession; 
   }  
   public int getId() { 
      return id; 
   }  
   @XmlElement 
   public void setId(int id) { 
      this.id = id; 
   } 
   public String getName() { 
      return name; 
   } 
   @XmlElement
   public void setName(String name) { 
      this.name = name; 
   } 
   public String getProfession() { 
      return profession; 
   } 
   @XmlElement 
   public void setProfession(String profession) { 
      this.profession = profession; 
   }   
}
```

**UserDao.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.ObjectInputStream; 
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;  

public class UserDao { 
   public List<User> getAllUsers(){ 

      List<User> userList = null; 
      try { 
         File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
         if (!file.exists()) { 
            User user = new User(1, "Mahesh", "Teacher"); 
            userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
            userList.add(user); 
            saveUserList(userList); 
         } 
         else{ 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); 
            userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject(); 
            ois.close(); 
         } 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }   
      return userList; 
   } 
   private void saveUserList(List<User> userList){ 
      try { 
         File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
         FileOutputStream fos;  
         fos = new FileOutputStream(file); 
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); 
         oos.writeObject(userList); 
         oos.close(); 
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } 
   }    
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.util.List; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
@Path("/UserService") 

public class UserService {  
   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();  
   @GET 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public List<User> getUsers(){ 
      return userDao.getAllUsers(); 
   }  
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
   id = "WebApp_ID" version = "3.0"> 
   <display-name>User Management</display-name> 
   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you checked your firewall?

Answer (score 0):

How did you run your application?
For Eclipse, please follow these steps to start the application.
**Right click your project -> Run As -> Run on Server**
Hope this helps you~

Comment: Hi, I means that how did you **RUN** the REST application, not **TEST** it. In my opinion, Postman is a tool to test web services.

Comment: using Tomcat apache

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your root application context is **/UserManagement**?
By default for tomcat web server -  root application context is equal to the name of your web artifact. So, make sure your UserManagement.war is copied to 'tomcat_distribution_folder'\webapps

I've checked locally - your web.xml descriptor is correctly configured. 
Since you are getting HTTP 404 error - is says your web server with the application is up and running.

Could you try to call endpoint with empty root context: **http://localhost:8080/rest/UserService/users**

or check the configuration of you web server and **use necessary root context** for the deployed application.

Comment: From the tutorial, it does visits the URL with **/UserManagement**, please check this picture ([link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/images/restful_postman.jpg)).

Comment: per tutorial: 
"To create a WAR file using eclipse, follow the option File → export → Web → War File and finally select project UserManagement and destination folder. To deploy a war file in Tomcat, place the UserManagement.war in the Tomcat Installation Directory → webapps directory and start the Tomcat."

**Have you copied the UserManagement.war to <tomcat_distribution_folder>\webapps  folder** ?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorials and faced the 500 response from the server When I tried to run in postman. Later I performed run on the server, it worked fine but with file not found an exception and Access denied for Users.dat file. I replaced .dat file with .txt and then I performed run on the server. It worked with no errors in the console and finally worked in postman too. I suggest you check the status of the tomcat apache server.